# Unable to use @client @export variable in query in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I simply want to use an @client (local cache) variable as a query parameter to my apollo server. The docs reference the @export directive (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#querying-local-state)

For some reason, I am unable to do something like

```
export const GET_COMPANY_DATA = gql`
  query GetCompanyData($id: ID!, $name: STRING!) {
    group @client @export(as: "name")
    getCompanyData(id: $id) {
      company {
        groups(name: $name) {
          data
        }
      }
    }
  }
;
```

Both queries work individually, for example:

```
{
  group @client
}
```

returns a string as it should from the local cache

```
export const GET_COMPANY_DATA = gql`
  query GetCompanyData($id: ID!, $name: STRING!) {
    getCompanyData(id: $id) {
      company {
        groups(name: $name) {
          data
        }
      }
    }
  }
;
```

returns the proper object type

In the docs, they show this example with no reference to the schema:

```
const query = gql`
  query currentAuthorPostCount($authorId: Int!) {
    currentAuthorId @client @export(as: "authorId")
    postCount(authorId: $authorId) @client
  }
`;
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I am missing some fundamental concept...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; when setting up apollo client, you must add the resolvers property even if you don't have any:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  **resolvers: {}**
});
```